# Row and column method missing on element.all

Tags: protractor, angularjs-e2e

I have the following setup, where I want Protractor to click on a row (or the checkbox in a row, either is fine):

```
<li data-ng-repeat="room in chatRooms | ***filters***">
    <div ng-click="toggleJoin(room.id)">
        <input type="checkbox" value="{{room.id}}" ng-checked="isChecked(room.id)" />
        <span>{{room.name}}</span>
    </div>
</li>
```

And I want to do this with my Page Object:

```
var PageObject = function() {
    this.lstChatRooms = element.all(by.repeater('room in chatRooms'));

    this.clickChatRoom = function(index) {
        this.lstChatRooms.row(index).column('{{room.id}}').click();
    };
};
```

But when I try to call `clickChatRoom` with some index in my test, I get an error saying the object has no method 'row', and I've seen the same behavior with 'column'. I'm not calling anything on the list of chat rooms prior to this in my test, so the promise should not be resolved at that point. What am I doing wrong?

Update: The issue may be caused by this [bug](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/706). Unless anyone can see that I'm doing something wrong with the API or something else.

Answer (score 0):

i can't test it right now, but this should work for you:

```
this.lstChatRooms.then(function(rooms) {
   rooms[index].findElement(by.tagName('input')).click();
});
```

Comment: I can't verify it unfortunately, I think I've found a bug that's blocking my testing (which may also be the source of this issue). https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/706